On modal open - blurred background or dark background
Does it affect the user experience if the background is black, white or blur when the modal is opened?
For example, if the background of the project creation modal is blurry, will the user think that they will go to a different page after the creation process.

In both examples the background color or blurriness don't make it clear where the user will go after interacting with the modal, but the actions in the modal should.

Modal dialogues are a pest invented back in the days as a quick hack to "linearize" a user input flow quickly on an otherwise advertised "multi tasking operating system and UI". And blurring or blackening the background only worsened the situation.
If the user is working with a certain UI flow and then the modal pops up, all the background information is inaccessible. No way of Copy&Paste information from there into the dialogue. Breaking all the "intuitive" workflows users were trained to use everywhere else.
Now with blurring, users cannot even look at the background information to check things they need on the modal popup maybe. And also they are forced to a focus they cannot chose freely.
Whereever possible: Avoid modal dialogs or keep them very small. Do not use background overlays like blurring etc. unless there is also an option to disable that "feature".

May I add one requirement: Always everywhere make modals resizable and draggable, so as to allow the user to reveal whatever they need to look up.
